# AVD The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_30 has terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator

i cant get my virtual device to run , i always get that "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_30 has terminated" error . i tried everything i could find on stackoverflow or any other website i could find but nothing seems to work. previous versions , enable hyper-v , disable hyper-v , check my disk space , changing some options in the advancedFeatures.ini and a lot more..
the error in the log i get is
`2023-09-14 15:49:29,782 \[ 298742\]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) 2023-09-14 15:49:29,782 \[ 298742\]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515`
i tried to google it but nothing came up. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How to find issue:
Entered  `/home/nerkn/Android/Sdk/tools`

List available devices:

```
 ./emulator -list-avds
```

start the erreous one:

```
./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30
```

error will appear properly:

```
ERROR   | Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 5144.734375 MB at /home/n/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_30.avd, need 7372.800000 MB.
```